Why is my C program not taking the second number as input and skips the second scanf?
I am creating a calculator using switch statement but after entering the operator, the program is ending without asking for the second number. How do I resolve this issue in my C code; any suggestions?
This is my code
int main(){

  double num1,num2,result;
  char op;

  printf("Enter the first no:-");
  scanf("%lf",&num1);
  printf("Enter the operator(+,*,/,-) :-");
  scanf("%ch",&op);
  printf("Enter the second number:-");
  scanf("%lf",&num2);
  return 0;
}

I tried deleting the whole code and write it from scratch but didn't work for me.

Please post all code directly in the question as text, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Does this answer your question? Scanf skips every other while loop in C

Welcome to SO. Unless you draw your code using MS Paint or Photoshop etc., a picture of it is not the right way to present it.

What is expected input for "%ch" format specifier? What is the role of h in it?

As a general rule, you should always check the return values of I/O functions like scanf. Otherwise you will not be able to detect and recover from incorrect input.

You can fix it by changing scanf("%ch",&op); to scanf(" %ch",&op);

Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for scanf automatically filter leading whitespace, but %c and %[] and %n do not. Adding a space in front of the % instructs scanf to filter leading whitespace here too. The reason is those three specifiers allow you to read every character including whitespace, but a way is provided so they behave like %d and %f and %s (etc) where needed.
